# If $x \not= 0$ and $\lambda x = 0$, then $\lambda = 0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification

I am trying to use the definition of vector spaces to prove that, if $x \not= 0$ and $\lambda x = 0$, then $\lambda = 0$.

Expressing the proposition differently, it seems to me that it is saying the following: If $x \not= 0$ and $\lambda x = 0$, then **there exists some** $\lambda \in E$ such that $\lambda x = 0$.

Let $x \not= 0$ and $\lambda x = 0$, where $x, \lambda \in E$.

Therefore, by the definition of vector spaces, there exists some $w \in E$ such that $x + \lambda = w$.

Since $x, w \in E$, let $w = x$ (that is, we select $w$ to be equal to $x$).

$\therefore x + \lambda = w \Rightarrow \lambda = w - x = 0 \ \ \ Q.E.D.$

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify whether or not this is correct.

Comment: If both $\lambda$ and $x$ are in the vector space $E$, what is the meaning of $\lambda x?$

Comment: @Idonknow Oops, you're right, I should have specified $\lambda$ as a scalar. The textbook did not specify it, so I just assumed it was an element of $E$.

Comment: It's the only multiplication in a vector space so it *must* be a scalar. The choice of letters is also significant.

Comment: I suppose that $\lambda$ is a scaler i.e. belongs to a field over which the vector space is defined. Vector space is closed under scaler multiplication. From here, it follows that $\lambda=0$.

Comment: @Koro Yes, that is another good one. But I think the textbook is looking for a more-involved proof in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence “If $x\ne0$ and $\lambda x=0$, then **there exists some** $\lambda\in E$ such that $\lambda x=0$.” makes no sense; what is the first $\lambda$?

And the problem of proving that $x\ne0$ and $\lambda x=0$ implies that $\lambda=0$  contains the implicit assumption that $x$ is a vector and that $\lambda$ is a scalar. But then $x+\lambda$ is meaningless.

You can prove what you want to prove as follows: if $\lambda\ne0$, then\begin{align}0&=\lambda^{-1}0\\&=\lambda^{-1}(\lambda x)\\&=\left(\lambda^{-1}\lambda\right)x\\&=1x\\&=x.\end{align}But we are assuming that $x\ne0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So this is a proof by contradiction?

Comment: Yes, it is a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @ThePointer You also need to show (it follows from the axioms too), that $\lambda 0=0$ for the vector $0$ and any scalar $\lambda$, this is often a lemma or extra exercise.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I am doing that now. I was actually just about to ask José: Can I use this same trick? Let $\lambda \not= 0$ and $\lambda x = 0$. Assume that $x \not= 0$. Then $$\begin{align} \lambda &= x^{-1} 0 \\ &= x^{-1} \lambda x \\ &= x^{-1}x \lambda \\ &= 1 \lambda \\ &= \lambda \end{align}$$ This is always true; but that's not what we were supposed to get, since we assumed the contradiction $x \not= 0$! So I assume the mistake was to divide by $x$ to have $\lambda = x^{-1}0$ at the beginning (that is, it is invalid to divide by a vector $x$ in a vector space)? Or is the error elsewhere?

Comment: @ThePointer $x^{-1} 0$ is meaningless. So **no**.

Comment: @ThePointer Use that $\lambda 0 = \lambda ( 0 + 0) = \lambda 0 + \lambda 0$. And any vector $z$ with $z+z=z$ must be $0$ so $\lambda0 =0$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Why can I not just immediately say that $\lambda x = 0 \Rightarrow x = \lambda^{-1} 0 = 0$, since $\lambda \not= 0$?

Comment: @ThePointer on the basis of what axiom?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma For the left-hand side, I would say $\lambda^{-1} (\lambda x) = \lambda^{-1} 0 \Rightarrow (\lambda^{-1} \lambda) x = \lambda^{-1} 0 \Rightarrow 1 x = \lambda^{-1} 0 \Rightarrow x = \lambda^{-1} 0$, but I guess you're right, since it's not clear that there's an axiom for the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Lemma: For the vector $0$ and *any* scalar $\lambda$ we have $\lambda 0 = 0$:

Define $z=\lambda 0$, then

- $z=\lambda 0 = \lambda(0+0)$ (as $0= 0+0$ in the vector space)
- distributivity tells us $\lambda(0+0)=\lambda 0 + \lambda 0  =z +z$.
- combining we get $z = z+z$.
- Then add $-z$ to both sides to get $0 = (z + (-z)) = (z+ z) + (-z)$.
- now, associativity for the right hand side gives us $0 = z + (z + (-z)) = z + 0 = z$.
- So $z=0 = \lambda 0$ and we're done.

Knowing that, suppose $\lambda x = 0$ for some $\lambda$ and $x \neq 0$. 
Now **assume** $\lambda \neq 0$ so that $\lambda^{-1}$ exists (as a scalar) such that $\lambda^{-1} \lambda=1$ (here we use that scalars are a *field*).

Then:

- $x = 1 x$ (axiom) so that:
- $x = (\lambda^{-1} \lambda)x$, using another axiom we get
- $x= \lambda^{-1}(\lambda x) = \lambda^{-1} 0 = 0$, where we substitute $\lambda x = 0$ and use the previous lemma for the scalar $\lambda^{-1}$.

So $x=0$, contradiction with $x \neq 0$, so the assumption $\lambda \neq 0$ was wrong and $\lambda = 0$. QED.